# How do I loop through **kwargs in Python?

Tags: python, keyword-argument

In the code below, I want to read `obj.subject` and place it into var `subject,` also read `obj.body` and place it into `body`. First I want to read the `kwargs` variables and search for keywords within the string to replace, if none exists then move on.

How can I iterate through `kwargs` in Python?

```
for key in kwargs:
    subject = str(obj.subject).replace('[%s]' % upper(key), kwargs[key])

for key in kwargs:
    body = str(obj.body).replace('[%s]' % upper(key), kwargs[key])

return (subject, body, obj.is_html)
```

Comment: Can you show example input (`obj.subject` and `obj.body` as well as `kwargs`) and desired output? It's hard to tell what you're asking without that.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**For Python 3 users:**

You can iterate through `kwargs` with `.items()`

```
subject = obj.subject
body = obj.body
for key, value in kwargs.items():
    subject = subject.replace('[%s]' % key.toupper(), value)
    body = body.replace('[%s]' % key.toupper(), value)

return (subject, body, obj.is_html)
```

**For Python 2 users:**

You can iterate through `kwargs` with `.iteritems()`:

```
subject = obj.subject
body = obj.body
for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
    subject = subject.replace('[%s]' % key.toupper(), value)
    body = body.replace('[%s]' % key.toupper(), value)

return (subject, body, obj.is_html)
```

Answer (score 22):

Just a quick note for those upgrading to Python 3.

In Python 3 it's almost the same:

```
subject = obj.subject
body = obj.body
for key, value in kwargs.items():
    subject = subject.replace('[{0}]'.format(key.toupper()), value)
    body = body.replace('[{0}]'.format(key.toupper()), value)

return (subject, body, obj.is_html)
```

Notice that `iteritems()` becomes `items()` as `dict` no longer has the method `iteritems`.

Answer (score 2):

you can iter on the dictionary as it provides by default **iteration** on its key.

```
subject = obj.subject
body = obj.body
    
for key in kwargs:
    subject = str(subject).replace([%s] % upper(key), kwargs[key])
    body = str(body).replace([%s] % upper(key), kwargs[key])

print(subject, body)
```

I tested it on **Python 3** and **Python 2** Interpreters and it is working totally fine for me so it will also work fine for you. There is a default for all the structures whether its List or Dictionary or tuple you can Iter on it easily in the python language.


**Attaching a photo depicting that we can do that so easily**.
[image: Photo For Proof]