# Is there a way of addressing all the inputs in a program?

Tags: python, input

Is there a way of addressing all the inputs in a program, for example, in an if statement or a for loop?

```
if (all inputs in the program) == int(all inputs in the program):
    print("your inputs are numbers")
```

and/or affecting them

```
for input in program:
    input = int(input)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "addressing all the inputs" ?

Comment: What are you asking? It's not clear.  Please see [mcve]

Comment: by _all the inputs_ do you mean command line arguments ?

Comment: If you mean command-line arguments, you should use `argparse` to handle validating the arguments when they are parsed.

Comment: inputs as in: x = input(), y = input()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one thing you could is keep a list of all inputs in your program. Then you'd be able to check if it contains only string representation of ints like so,

```
input_list = []

x = input("Enter somehting") 
input_list.append(x)

y = input("Enter somehting")
input_list.append(y)

if [x for x in input_list if x.isdigit()] == input_list :
    print("your inputs are numbers")
else:
    print("your inputs are not all numbers")
```

In order to clarify the code, I'm creating a list using list comprehension which will contains all inputs that are a string representation of an int and comparing with the actual list of inputs. If both are the same, it guarantee that all inputs are numbers.

Alternatively, if your goal is to cast every input, use list comprehension on your `input_list`

```
casted_list = [int(x) for x in input_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you have one main function you enter in the program and pass all the kwargs into that method you could then loop them.

```
main(**kwargs):
    function1()
    function2()
```

See this answer. [How do I loop through **kwargs in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899129/how-do-i-loop-through-kwargs-in-python)

```
for key, value in kwargs.items():
```